# Get input method on a FormGroup instance returns null

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I'm trying to show custom error message only if the `foo` input is not valid, but it seems like this line code is null: `myForm.get('foo')`.

Here is the simplify `component.html`:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formGroupName="myData">
      Foo: <input type="text" formControlName="foo">
      <span *ngIf="!myForm.get('foo').valid">Not valid foo</span>
      Boo: <input type="text" formControlName="boo">
  </div>
  Zoo: <input type="text" formControlName="zoo">
</form>
```

And the `component.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      'myData': new FormGroup({
        'foo': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        'boo': new FormControl(null),
      }),
      'zoo': new FormControl(null)
    });
  }
}
```

Why is this line of code `myForm.get('foo')` is being evaluated as null? what am I doing wrong? as you may see the `foo` is a valid `FormControl` object.

Comment: Yes, that's valid Form but you're trying to access to undefined control since missed nested part. It should be `myForm.get('myData.foo')`

Comment: hey @yurzui thanks! yeah it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the nested form group control from the main form group.

Try:

```
this.myForm.get(['myData', 'foo']);
```

Or

```
this.myForm.get('myData.foo');
```